# Create self hosted private GitLab Pages site with same permissions as self hosted private GitLab project?

Tags: git, gitlab

With a private GitLab project (gitlab-ce) at `https://gitlab.example.com/user/project.git`, how can I create a GitLab Pages site from files in that project's repository that has same permissions as the repository?

E.g, `user1` owns the private project and invited `user2` and `user3` but not `user4` and not the public to have access to the repository. Can `user1` create GitLab Pages site that only offers access to `user1`, `user2`, and `user3` with their correct GitLab username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This has been suggested and is under consideration but is not yet implemented.
All gitlab pages are public.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/33422

Solutions right now is self-hosted gitlab or using gitlab CI to copy the artifacts somewhere where you have control over access.